# Rails: undefined method `cover_letter' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

In my rails application I have this three models User, Job and Job_application the association between the 3 is below

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :job_applications
  has_many :applicants, :through => :job_applications, :source => :user   

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_applications

class JobApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :job_applications  
  has_many :applied_jobs, :through => :job_applications, :source => :job
```

In my Job controller I have this method so that user can apply to job

```
  def apply
    @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id])  
    @job_application = JobApplication.new
    @job_application.user_id = current_user.id
    @job_application.job_id = @job.id

    if @job_application.save
      JobMailer.somebody_applied(@job).deliver
      redirect_to job_url(@job)
    else
      render :action => "show"
    end
  end
```

and my Job view page I have this code for the apply method

```
<button type="button" id="control_gen_5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <span>Envoyer un candidature</span>
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close close-this" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apply to <%= @job.job_title %></h4>
      </div>
      <p><%= current_user.full_name%></p>
      <%= form_for @job, :url => apply_job_path(@job), :method => :post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :job_applications, @job.job_applications.build do |s| %>
          <%= s.hidden_field :user_id %>
          <%= s.hidden_field :job_id %>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
              <div class="form-inputs">
                <%= s.text_area :cover_letter, :input_html => { :rows => 5, :class => 'span12', :value => cookies[:cover_letter] }, :label => false %>
              </div>
            </p>
          </div>
        <% end %>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= f.submit 'Postuler', :class => 'btn btn-info', :name => nil %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also this code so I can view who has applied for a job and their cover letter

```
</ul>
<% @job.job_applications.each do |job_application| %>
  <li>
    <%= job_application.user.full_name %>
    <%= job_application.cover_letter %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

But the is that only the user full name are displayed and not the cover letter.

I have tried this code in my rails console

```
j.job_applications.last   where   j = Job.last
```

this has give me  this

```
#<JobApplication id: 42, job_id: 24, user_id: 49, cover_letter: nil,  created_at: "2015-04-20 14:22:31", updated_at: "2015-04-20 14:22:31">
```

Any one can help to know why I'm getting nil for cover_letter

Comment: Can you post logs when you submit form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems `cover_letter` is an attribute of `JobApplication` but you never set it to anything in the `#apply` action in the controller.

Current Method:

```
def apply
  @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id])  
  @job_application = JobApplication.new
  @job_application.user_id = current_user.id
  @job_application.job_id = @job.id
  # where are you setting cover_letter? 
  # this is why it does not save
  if @job_application.save
    JobMailer.somebody_applied(@job).deliver
    redirect_to job_url(@job)
  else
    render :action => "show"
  end
end
```

Try this:

```
def apply
  @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  #since you are excepting nested attributes through job
  # all you need to do is update the job appropriately using update_attributes      
  if @job.update_attributes(job_application_params)
    JobMailer.somebody_applied(@job).deliver
    redirect_to job_url(@job)
  else
    render :action => "show"
  end
end

private
  def job_application_params
     #since we are building the application off of the job 
     # there is no need for the job_id attribute as this will be 
     # forcefully implied from the parent job
     params.require(:job).permit({job_applications_attributes:[:cover_letter,:user_id]})
  end
```

your params should be coming through as:

```
job:{
  #...
  job_application_attributes:[
     "0" =>{
       user_id: ###,
       job_id: ###,
       cover_letter: ""
     }
  ]
}
```

right now you are ignoring the `cover_letter` in the params `Hash` completely this is why it is nil. Also since we re building the application from the job there is no need to specify the job_id in the fields_for section at all.

Comment: without using strong params I'm getting this error  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError The first solution also raise this error unknown attribute 'job_applications_attributes' for JobApplication.

Comment: @rocki you did not specify rails version so I added both since you are getting that error you are clearly using `strong_parameters` I will update the answer. Also since we are excepting nested attributes you can just update the job see my revisions above.

Comment: This has worked for me but actually I'm getting another error for the user full_name undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass in <%= job_application.user.full_name %>

Comment: @rocki please post your params as I cannot help any further without seeing why it is not setting `user_id`. The error you are receiving is because `job_application.user` is `nil` thus no `full_name` method. Also I do not see you setting `user_id` at all in the form. where is this supposed to come from? `current_user` possibly? If so please advise and I will help you rewrite the form

Comment: I can get the applicant name using this </ul>
<% @job.applicants.each do |appli| %>
  <li>
    <%= appli.full_name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul> I don't know if this tje best solution could you please suggest a better solution for my apply form

Comment: @rocki where you have `@job.job_applications.build` change it to `@job.job_applications.build(user_id: current_user.id)`. This way `s.hidden_field :user_id` will actually have a value right now you are not setting it and thus it remains `nil`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, and please what you think of my design It is better to use nested attributes or must I create the apply method in the job_applications controller any other advises or suggestions are welcome

Comment: @rocki because of your current design and the fact that a user should only apply once per job I would make a JobApplicationsController and handle the standard CRUD there instead.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(job_applications_attributes: [:id, :job_id, :user_id, :cover_letter, :resume, :_destroy])
end
```

On controller you need to set params to the new JobApplication like:

```
@job_application = JobApplication.new(job_params)
```

Comment: The problem is you are not setting cover_letter to job_application. I do not remember exactly how nested attributes are set on params. Inspect params to confirm that.

Comment: I have already do that like this def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(job_applications_attributes: [:id, :job_id, :user_id, :cover_letter, :resume, :_destroy])

Comment: Good. Now you can set your permitted attributes to job_application: `@job_application = JobApplication.new(job_params)`.

Comment: I have already tried this and it give me this errors unknown attribute 'job_applications_attributes' for JobApplication.

Comment: @rocki this is because the syntax is wrong for nested parameters you need to wrap them in a Hash like so `params.require(:job).permit({job_applications_attributes: [:id, :job_id, :user_id, :cover_letter, :resume, :_destroy]})` this way `strong_parameters` knows these are resources that will respond to the given methods with acceptable scalar values. Although please note you are not sending `resume` at all currently and even `_destroy` is questionable based on your implementation I cannot see where this field is generated.

Comment: @engineersmnky give a better explanation on him answer